# VirtualBoxがエラーで再インストールできません

Tags: virtualbox, macos

マックのローカル環境構築でVirtualBoxを使いたいのですが、初めにインストールした時はインストールはできたのですが仮想マシンを立ち上げることができなかったので、消してインストールし直そうとしたらできなくなりました。
ドットインストールで学んでいるのでVirtualBoxをできればインストールして早く使いたいです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　Virtualbox に限らず、「○○が動かなくなった」という際には、単に動かなくなったというだけだと対処法を考えることが難しいです。なぜインストールし直すことができなくなったと思われたのか、詳細を追記して頂ければと思います。エラーログがあればそれをコピー＆ペーストして頂ければよいです。他にもたとえば「Virtualbox をどのようにインストールしたのか」「どのようにアンインストールしたのか」などが具体的な手順として追記してあれば、回答の助けになると思います。質問文下の「編集」から自由に追記できますので、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: Macでバーチャルボックスのアンインストールをする際には、インストール時に使ったdmgファイル内の、VirtualBox_Uninstall.toolというファイルをダブルクリックしてアンインストールする必要がありますが、消したとはどの様な操作をしたのか、具体的に書くとアドバイスが貰いやすいかと思います（特に消す際に、VirtualBox_Uninstall.toolを使ったか否か）。同様にインストールできないというのもどういうメッセージが出てどんな操作中にどういうメッセージが出て止まるのかも質問に書き加えることで、より適切なアドバイスがもらえると思います。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。今の状況を貼ってみたのでよろしければ見てください。

Answer (score 4):

コメントにも書きましたが、VirtualBoxのdmgファイルを開いた右下にある、
`VirtualBox_Uninstall.tool`というファイルをダブルクリックして実行してみてください。

想像ですが、アプリケーションフォルダー内に作られたVitrualBoxだけをゴミ箱に入れて削除して、
アンインストールしたと思ってしまい、アプリケーションフォルダー以外に作られた環境設定ファイルなどが消えていないため上書きできずにエラーになっていると思われます。

`VirtualBox_Uninstall.tool`は良く出来ていて、既に手動で削除されてしまったファイルがあっても、そこでエラーで止まらずに削除が必要で、残っているファイルだけを削除してくれるように作られていますので、一部ファイルを削除してしまったた後でも、動きますので安心して試してみてください。